# jQuery 1.3.2 remove empty values

Tags: jquery

Hello I use this code to remove empty input text fields from my form:

```
 $('input:text[value=\"\"]', '#submForm').remove();
```

How do I achieve the same but with empty dropdown values like the below one?

```
<select><option value=""></option></select>
```

I need to remove the empty dropdown with the jQuery remove();

How do I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this (I don't think you can use it with the attributes because the value is on the option. Do you want to remove the option or the select item?

```
    $("select").each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == "")
         $(this).remove();
     });
```

Comment: I want to remove the entire select item if the dropdown remains on the empty value(means the user has not selected any value on that select). Can you help me with this?

Comment: @DiegoP - I think this should work. You would call this when the user submits form I assume?

Answer (score 6):

```
$('select option[value=""]').remove();
```

**Demo:** [http://jsfiddle.net/trXp8/](http://jsfiddle.net/trXp8/1/)

Or, you mean in between the `option` tag, then:

```
$('select option:empty').remove();
```

**Demo:** [http://jsfiddle.net/X6BKA/](http://jsfiddle.net/X6BKA/1/)

**EDIT:**

Okay. So you're referring to a multiple selection? Then this will do:

```
$('select option:not(:selected)').remove();
```

This will remove the options that have not been selected.

**Demo:** [http://jsfiddle.net/Y4RZj](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4RZj/2)

Comment: Ups I did not explain it fine. I want to remove all the values of the dropdown if no values have been selected. I have an empty value, that is the first one and then other two values. If the dropdown stays on the empty value it means the user did not touch that, and in that case all the values of that dropdown should be removed an not included. Do you understand? Thank you